# Как спарсить значения из xml документа

Tags: c#, xml

Вот содержимое xml документа

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Filename version="0.0.0.1" platform="windows">
    <Settings>
       <Setting name="Use proxy">ON</Setting>
       ....
            <Tabs>
                  <Tab selected="1">
                     <LocalPath>C:\Users\admin\</LocalPath>
                     <Pass encoding="base64">Mjxs1XZPODqzv=</Pass>
                  </Tab>
            </Tabs>
    </Setting>
</Filename>
```

Как можно спарсить значения `LocalPath` и `Pass encoding=`

Попробовал из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580857/xmldocument-getelementsbytagname-within-a-specified-block-in-c-sharp) примера сделать так:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("ProxyViewer.xml");
var bookNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Tabs/Tab selected=\"1\"");
foreach (XmlNode item in bookNodes)
{
    string locPath = item.SelectSingleNode("./LocalPath").InnerText;
    string pass = item.SelectSingleNode("./Pass encoding=").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("locPath {0} pass: {1}",locPath, pass);
}
```

Но оно не находит

Comment: `//Tabs/Tab selected=\"1\"` - это XPath, который вы написали с ошибкой. [Шпаргалку дам, поймете что не так быстро](https://devhints.io/xpath). А так, он должен быть примерно следующим: `//Tabs/Tab[@selected='1']`. А вообще, я вам советую пойти в сторону LINQ, как по мне он для XML в разы удобней, по вашей ссылке 2-м ответом (да и в первом начало на LINQ) написан даже пример.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже упоминалось в комментарии @EvgeniyZ, лучше использовать **LINQ to XML** API. Он доступен в .Net Framework с 2007 года.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\Temp\ProxyViewer.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    string selected = "1";

    var xelem = xdoc.Descendants("Tab")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("selected").Value.Equals(selected));

    Console.WriteLine("locPath: '{0}', pass: '{1}'"
        , xelem.Elements("LocalPath").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
        , xelem.Elements("Pass").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);

}
```

**Результат**

```
locPath: 'C:\Users\admin\', pass: 'Mjxs1XZPODqzv='
```